# find the min and max values in javaScript, i get incorrect result, what is wrong?

Tags: javascript

Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of two space-separated long integers.

the expected Output is

> 299 9271

my output is

> 299 9266

the input is

> 7 69 2 221 8974

this is my function

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    let panjang = arr.length,
        max = arr.slice(0, panjang-1),
        min = arr.slice(1, panjang),
        maxSum = max.reduce((total, item) => total+item),
        minSum = min.reduce((total, item) => total+item);      
    process.stdout.write(`${maxSum} ${minSum}`);    
}
```

can someone help me please?

Comment: Debug the variables. You will clearly see that min and max is not what you think it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By slicing from 0 to 4, and from 1 to 5, you're assuming that the array is already sorted, and that the items at index 0 and 5 are the maximum and minimum - which they aren't.

Either sort the array first, or use `Math.max` / `Math.min` to identify the smallest and largest, and subtract from the sum.

```js
const arr = [7, 69, 2, 221, 8974];
const sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
const min = Math.min(...arr);
const max = Math.max(...arr);
console.log(sum - max, sum - min);
```